# Javascript Date(dateString) returns NaN on specific server and browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iis, date

I'm using the Javascript Date(string) constructor with a date format of "yyyy-mm-dd". The constructor works just fine in IE 9 and Firefox unless the app is running on our testing VM which is running IIS. If it's on the VM, in IE 9 it returns 'NaN', but still works normally in Firefox.

```
    var dateAsString = "2011-11-09";
    var dateCreated = new Date(dateAsString);
```

I was under the assumption that the server had nothing to do with client-side Javascript. Any suggestions?

Comment: Pretty sure that the server has nothing to do with client-side Javascript as the client (the person visiting the site) runs that code, not the server.

Comment: @jakx I know, that's why I am confused by this.

Comment: Check the document mode in the developer tools of IE (F12) on both servers. I suspect they differ.

Comment: @Phrogz wins! Thanks. Now I can sleep tonight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest attempting a more reliable form of date parsing. The example below uses `setFullYear()`. Does IE produce a different result with the code below?

```
/**Parses string formatted as YYYY-MM-DD to a Date object.
   * If the supplied string does not match the format, an 
   * invalid Date (value NaN) is returned.
   * @param {string} dateStringInRange format YYYY-MM-DD, with year in
   * range of 0000-9999, inclusive.
   * @return {Date} Date object representing the string.
   */
  function parseISO8601(dateStringInRange) {
    var isoExp = /^\s*(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)\s*$/,
        date = new Date(NaN), month,
        parts = isoExp.exec(dateStringInRange);

    if(parts) {
      month = +parts[2];
      date.setFullYear(parts[1], month - 1, parts[3]);
      if(month != date.getMonth() + 1) {
        date.setTime(NaN);
      }
    }
    return date;
  }
```

Source: http://jibbering.com/faq/#parseDate

Comment: That worked. This still baffles me though. The server serving up the JS shouldn't matter right? My code worked in IE when I ran it on localhost.

Comment: I had a date which also included the time and zone (only needed the date). I edited your regex on line 2 and removed both the ^ and $ from it. Otherwise, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 9):

Just use slashes instead of hyphens if you can.

---

EDIT: Expanded clarification...

The [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard format uses the hyphen as a date separator.  My answer does not mean you do not need to follow standards.  You can use slashes only for the Date constructor if necessary.

Comment: That certainly sounds attractive. Can you confirm that all other major browsers support the slash-separated format as well?

Comment: Works like a charm! :-)

Answer (score 9):

And for those of us who want to know *how* to replace hyphens (aka dashes) with slashes:

```
new Date(dashToSlash(string));
```

That uses this function:

```
function dashToSlash(string){
  var response = string.replace(/-/g,"/");
  //The slash-g bit says: do this more than once
  return response;
}
```

In my case it's much easier to convert hyphens to slashes selectively (only where it's needed for the Date() function) than to replace the date format everywhere in my code.

Note: you really need to define a separate 'response' variable and assign it the value of the replace operation result. If you don't, the string is returned unaltered in Chrome. That's not a huge problem, since Chrome doesn't have a problem with hyphenated date strings to begin with. But still...

Comment: `you really need to define a separate 'response' variable and assign it the value of the replace operation result. If you don't, the string is returned unaltered in Chrome.` what?

Answer (score 4):

It's because of the date format. For some reason, IE and Safari get tripped up with `yyyy-mm-dd`. Use another date format and you should be all set.

It's talked about here:
http://biostall.com/javascript-new-date-returning-nan-in-ie-or-invalid-date-in-safari

Comment: But, the real problem is that it DOES work in IE when I run the app on my localhost (Visual Studio server). It doesn't work in IE when it's on a different server.

Comment: Does the other server have a different version of IE installed?

Comment: Nope, two different tabs open in the same IE 9. Same JS code, different behavior.

Comment: @Gagege: Are you using `localhost` or do you have a more realistic domain name, e.g. `dev.example.com`.  IE may be acting differently depending on the zone it associates the site with (Trusted / Intranet / Internet / Untrusted / My Computer).

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski That would make sense, but it turns out "document mode" in IE9 was set to IE7 for one of the servers.

Comment: It can be frustrating that IE seems to do different things on server vs some clients, but essentially it's irrelevant. Since it doesn't work properly in all reasonable circumstances, you need a workaround.